# Measure elapsed time in Swift

Tags: swift, time, nsdate, elapsedtime

How can we measure the time elapsed for running a function in Swift? I am trying to display the elapsed time like this: "Elapsed time is .05 seconds". Saw that [in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776053/878414), we can use System.nanoTime(), are there any equivalent methods available in Swift to accomplish this?

Please have a look at the sample program:

```swift
func isPrime(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
    var i = 0;
    for i=2; i<number; i++ {
        if number % i == 0, i != 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

var number = 5915587277

if isPrime(number) {
    print("Prime number")
} else {
    print("NOT a prime number")
}
```

Comment: it is unrelated to your time-measuring issue, but the loop can be stopped at `sqrt(number)` instead of `number`, and you can save a little more time – but there are much more ideas optimising seeking primes.

Comment: @holex Please ignore the algorithm used. I am trying to figure out how we can measure the elapsed time?

Comment: you can use `NSDate` objects and you can measure the difference between them.

Comment: If you are using XCode, I recommend you use the new performance testing feature. It does all the heavy lifting for you and even runs it multiple times and gives you the average time with its standard deviation...

Comment: @Roshan Although perhaps not an answer I'd love to see your comment on Xcode's performance testing feature expanded. Where can I learn more? How can I use it to compare the time taken by various methods contributing to a run?

Comment: @dumbledad You can measure performance of whole blocks directly in unit tests. For example, [see this](http://samuelmullen.com/2014/10/performance_testing_in_swift/). If you want to break a run down further(say, line by line code), check out [Time Profiler](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments--mobile-9403) which is part of Instruments. This is much more powerful and comprehensive.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

**Update**

With Swift 5.7, everything below becomes obsolete. Swift 5.7 introduces the concept of a [Clock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/clock) which has a function designed to do exactly what is required here.

There are two concrete examples of a `Clock` provided: `ContinuousClock` and `SuspendingClock`. The former keeps ticking when the system is suspending and the latter does not.

The following is an example of what to do in Swift 5.7

```
func doSomething()
{
    for i in 0 ..< 1000000
    {
        if (i % 10000 == 0)
        {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

let clock = ContinuousClock()

let result = clock.measure(doSomething)

print(result) // On my laptop, prints "0.552065882 seconds"
```

It also allows you to measure closures directly, of course

```
let clock = ContinuousClock()

let result = clock.measure {
    for i in 0 ..< 1000000
    {
        if (i % 10000 == 0)
        {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

print(result) // "0.534663798 seconds"
```

---

**Pre Swift 5.7**

Here's a Swift function I wrote to measure [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/about) problems in Swift

As of Swift 3, there is now a version of Grand Central Dispatch that is "swiftified". So the correct answer is probably to use the [DispatchTime API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchtime).

My function would look something like:

```
// Swift 3
func evaluateProblem(problemNumber: Int, problemBlock: () -> Int) -> Answer
{
    print("Evaluating problem \(problemNumber)")

    let start = DispatchTime.now() // <<<<<<<<<< Start time
    let myGuess = problemBlock()
    let end = DispatchTime.now()   // <<<<<<<<<<   end time

    let theAnswer = self.checkAnswer(answerNum: "\(problemNumber)", guess: myGuess)

    let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds // <<<<< Difference in nano seconds (UInt64)
    let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000 // Technically could overflow for long running tests

    print("Time to evaluate problem \(problemNumber): \(timeInterval) seconds")
    return theAnswer
}
```

---

#### Old answer

For Swift 1 and 2, my function uses NSDate:

```
// Swift 1
func evaluateProblem(problemNumber: Int, problemBlock: () -> Int) -> Answer
{
    println("Evaluating problem \(problemNumber)")

    let start = NSDate() // <<<<<<<<<< Start time
    let myGuess = problemBlock()
    let end = NSDate()   // <<<<<<<<<<   end time

    let theAnswer = self.checkAnswer(answerNum: "\(problemNumber)", guess: myGuess)

    let timeInterval: Double = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start) // <<<<< Difference in seconds (double)

    println("Time to evaluate problem \(problemNumber): \(timeInterval) seconds")
    return theAnswer
}
```

<sub>Note that using NSdate for timing functions is discouraged: "*The system time may decrease due to synchronization with external time references or due to an explicit user change of the clock.*".</sub>

Comment: This appears to give results good up to around +/-2microsec.  Maybe that varies by platform, however.

Comment: Using calendar time for measuring execution time is really ill-advised. There's no guarantee your thread has been active on the CPU (i.e. it could have spend most of its time waiting to be scheduled on the CPU)

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Sorry, but it works well enough. There will only be a problem if the the thread gets pre-emptively switched out which is unlikely on a modern multicore CPU.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Another point is of course that the question asks for *elapsed* time - not time spent actually running on the CPU.

Comment: swift3 doesn't work for me, it returns 0.0114653027 which i know for a fact that is not true, the one with dates returns 4.77720803022385sec

Comment: @CristiBăluță Any chance you could do some debugging to see where it goes wrong? I can't see an obvious error in the code.

Comment: I've fixed a bug: It was `1_000_0000_000` instead of `1_000_000_000`. (See the block with four 0s?)

Comment: Unfortunately not. The uptime is completely out for some reason. I have a test which says took 1004959766 nanoseconds (about a second), but was definitely running for about 40 seconds. I used `Date` alongside, and sure enough that reports 41.87 seconds. I don't know what `uptimeNanoseconds` is doing, but it's not reporting the correct duration.

Comment: @jowie I just ran the code with the following closure `{
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 40.0)
    return 2
}` and it gives the right answer (just over 40 seconds)

Comment: @JeremyP but that's for the `Thread` class, not `DispatchTime`. The former takes a `TimeInterval` in seconds. `uptimeNanoseconds` is a `UInt64`.

Comment: @jowie Yes. That was to make the closure take 40 seconds to run.  Using that closure as `problemBlock` and the timing code in my Swift 3 answer, I get almost exactly 40 seconds reported. My code gives the right answer.

Comment: Is there advantage to your solution vs the solution below (written by Klass)?

Comment: @Honey There are two reasons why I prefer my solution over that of Klass: 1. It doesn't use core foundation, which, I think, might get deprecated. The `DispatchTime` version is probably "the future". 2. In order to use it, I just pass the block of code to a function call. Klass's solution requires you to annotate the code to be timed with a before and after step.  Not saying mine is better or worse but I think using it is a bit cleaner.

Comment: What is "checkanswer"?

Comment: @Neo42 it compared the return value from `problemBlock` against the correct answer and printed a nasty message if they differed (if they were different, it meant the code had regressed). What it does is totally irrelevant to the point of this SO question.

Comment: Sorry for the big edit, prioritizing your newer solution, but I would even recommend to delete your NSDate code entirely: it's totally unreliable to use NSDate: NSDate is based on system clock, which can change at any time due to many different reasons, such as network time sync (NTP) updating the clock (happens often to adjust for drift), DST adjustments, leap seconds, and user manual adjustment of the clock. Additionally, you can't publish anymore on the AppStore any app using Swift 1: Swift 3 is the bare minimum. So there is no point to keep your NSDate code other than to say "don't do it".

Comment: @Cœur your criticism of the NSDate version is valid (except DST changes won't affect NSDate which is always in GMT), and your edit to reverse the order is definitely an improvement.

Comment: Note that the time that DispatchTime returns is not incremented when the device is sleeping

Answer (score 87):

This is a handy timer class based on `CoreFoundation`s [`CFAbsoluteTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfabsolutetime):

```
import CoreFoundation

class ParkBenchTimer {
    let startTime: CFAbsoluteTime
    var endTime: CFAbsoluteTime?

    init() {
        startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    }

    func stop() -> CFAbsoluteTime {
        endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

        return duration!
    }

    var duration: CFAbsoluteTime? {
        if let endTime = endTime {
            return endTime - startTime
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let timer = ParkBenchTimer()

// ... a long runnig task ...

print("The task took \(timer.stop()) seconds.")
```

Comment: "_Repeated calls to this function do not guarantee monotonically increasing results._" according to its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent).

Comment: More context: "Repeated calls to this function do not guarantee monotonically increasing results. The system time may decrease **due to synchronization with external time references or due to an explicit user change of the clock**."

Comment: Developer should take "synchronization with external time references" and "an explicit user change of the clock" into account. Did you mean that it's impossible for the two situation to happen?

Comment: @FranklinYu no, I just wanted to state these are the two possible reasons. If you rely on always getting monotonically increasing values there are other options.

Comment: sometimes I wish to measure a short period of time; if synchronization happens during that, I may end up with negative time. There is actually `mach_absolute_time` which does not suffer from this problem, so I am wondering why that one is not widely known. Maybe just because it is not well documented.

Comment: This is a cool name with somehow related semantics. Thanks.

Answer (score 75):

### Use [`clock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html), [`ProcessInfo.systemUptime`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/processinfo/1414553-systemuptime), or [`DispatchTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime) for simple start-up time.

---

There are, as far as I know, at least ten ways to measure elapsed time:

#### Monotonic Clock based:

1. [`ProcessInfo.systemUptime`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/processinfo/1414553-systemuptime).
2. [`mach_absolute_time`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1398/_index.html) with `mach_timebase_info` as mentioned in [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753909/).
3. `clock()` in [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html).
4. `times()` in [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/times.html). (Too complicated since we need
   to consider user-time v.s. system-time, and child processes are
   involved.)
5. [`DispatchTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime) (a wrapper around Mach time API) as mentioned by JeremyP in accepted answer.
6. [`CACurrentMediaTime()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime).

#### Wall Clock based:

(never use those for metrics: see below why)

7. `NSDate`/`Date` as mentioned by others.
8. `CFAbsoluteTime` as mentioned by others.
9. [`DispatchWallTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchwalltime).
10. `gettimeofday()` in [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html).

---

Option 1, 2 and 3 are elaborated below.

### Option 1: Process Info API in Foundation

```
do {
    let info = ProcessInfo.processInfo
    let begin = info.systemUptime
    // do something
    let diff = (info.systemUptime - begin)
}
```

where `diff:NSTimeInterval` is the elapsed time by seconds.

### Option 2: Mach C API

```
do {
    var info = mach_timebase_info(numer: 0, denom: 0)
    mach_timebase_info(&info)
    let begin = mach_absolute_time()
    // do something
    let diff = Double(mach_absolute_time() - begin) * Double(info.numer) / Double(info.denom)
}
```

where `diff:Double` is the elapsed time by nano-seconds.

### Option 3: POSIX clock API

```
do {
    let begin = clock()
    // do something
    let diff = Double(clock() - begin) / Double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
}
```

where `diff:Double` is the elapsed time by seconds.

### Why Not Wall-Clock Time for Elapsed Time?

In documentation of [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1543542-cfabsolutetimegetcurrent):

> Repeated calls to this function do not guarantee monotonically
> increasing results.

Reason is similar to [`currentTimeMillis` vs `nanoTime` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776053):

> You can't use the one for the other purpose. The reason is that no
> computer's clock is perfect; it always drifts and occasionally
> needs to be corrected. This correction might either happen
> manually, or in the case of most machines, there's a process that
> runs and continually issues small corrections to the system clock
> ("wall clock"). These tend to happen often. Another such correction
> happens whenever there is a leap second.

Here `CFAbsoluteTime` provides wall clock time instead of start-up
time. `NSDate` is wall clock time as well.

Comment: the best answer - but what, the hell, is the best approach to take?!

Comment: Option 5 suited best to me. If you considering multi-platform code try this one. Both Darwin and Glibc libraries have `clock()` function.

Comment: For the System Clock based solutions: I had success with `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime`, `mach_absolute_time()`, `DispatchTime.now()` and `CACurrentMediaTime()`. But the solution with `clock()` was not converting to seconds properly. So I would advise to update your first sentence to: "**_Use ProcessInfo.systemUptime or DispatchTime for accurate start-up time._**"

Comment: Great answer. Explained everything.

Comment: Great answer. If I may, option 2 could be optimised using `clock_gettime_nsec_np(CLOCK_UPTIME_RAW)` which does the time base conversion for you and provides nanosec value (see http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/clock_gettime_nsec_np/)

Answer (score 60):

Swift 4 shortest answer:

```
let startingPoint = Date()
//  ... intensive task
print("\(startingPoint.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1) seconds elapsed")
```

It will print you something like *1.02107906341553  seconds elapsed* (time of course will vary depending on the task, I'm just showing this for you guys to see the decimal precision level for this measurement).

Hope it helps someone in Swift 4 from now on!

Update

If you want to have a generic way of testing portions of code, I'd suggest the next snippet:

```
func measureTime(for closure: @autoclosure () -> Any) {
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    closure()
    let diff = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
    print("Took \(diff) seconds")
}
```

Usage

```
measureTime(for: <insert method signature here>)
```

**Console log**

```
Took xx.xxxxx seconds
```

Comment: Can someone explain why * -1?

Comment: @MaksimKniazev Because it's negative value, people want positive one!

Comment: @thachnb I had no idea "startingPoint.timeIntervalSinceNow" produces negative value ...

Comment: @MaksimKniazev Apple says that: If the date object is earlier than the current date and time, this property’s value is negative.

Answer (score 20):

Just Copy and Paste this function. Written in swift 5.
Copying JeremyP here.

```
func calculateTime(block : (() -> Void)) {
        let start = DispatchTime.now()
        block()
        let end = DispatchTime.now()
        let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
        let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
        print("Time: \(timeInterval) seconds")
    }
```

Use it like

```
calculateTime {
     exampleFunc()// function whose execution time to be calculated
}
```

Comment: I tried to do something like this but it ends up into arithmetic overflow error!

Answer (score 18):

```
let start = NSDate()

for index in 1...10000 {
    // do nothing
}

let elapsed = start.timeIntervalSinceNow

// elapsed is a negative value.
```

Comment: abs(start.timeIntervalSinceNow)//<--positive value

Comment: pretty much the most straight forward solution I've seen, thank you

Answer (score 7):

It looks like **iOS 13** introduced a new API to use with `DispatchTime` that removes a need to calculate the difference between two timestamps manually.

[`distance(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime/3329234-distance)

```swift
let start: DispatchTime = .now()
heavyTaskToMeasure()
let duration = start.distance(to: .now())
print(duration) 
// prints: nanoseconds(NUMBER_OF_NANOSECONDS_BETWEEN_TWO_TIMESTAMPS)
```

Sadly the documentation is not provided, but after doing some tests it looks like the `.nanoseconds` case is always returned.

With a simple extension you could convert the `DispatchTimeInterval` to `TimeInterval`. [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233453/8160613)

```swift
extension TimeInterval {
    init?(dispatchTimeInterval: DispatchTimeInterval) {
        switch dispatchTimeInterval {
        case .seconds(let value):
            self = Double(value)
        case .milliseconds(let value):
            self = Double(value) / 1_000
        case .microseconds(let value):
            self = Double(value) / 1_000_000
        case .nanoseconds(let value):
            self = Double(value) / 1_000_000_000
        case .never:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create a `time` function for measuring you calls.
I am inspired by [Klaas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292145/klaas) answer.

```
func time <A> (f: @autoclosure () -> A) -> (result:A, duration: String) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let result = f()
    let endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    return (result, "Elapsed time is \(endTime - startTime) seconds.")
}
```

This function would allow you to call it like this `time (isPrime(7))` which would return a tuple containing the result and a string description of the elapsed time.

If you only wish the elapsed time you can do this `time (isPrime(7)).duration`

Comment: "Repeated calls to this function do not guarantee monotonically increasing results." according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent).

Answer (score 3):

Simple helper function for measuring execution time with closure.

```
func printExecutionTime(withTag tag: String, of closure: () -> ()) {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    closure()
    print("#\(tag) - execution took \(CACurrentMediaTime() - start) seconds")
}
```

**Usage:**

```
printExecutionTime(withTag: "Init") {
    // Do your work here
}
```

**Result:**
`#Init - execution took 1.00104497105349 seconds`

Answer (score 2):

you can measure the *nanoseconds* like e.g. this:

```
let startDate: NSDate = NSDate()

// your long procedure

let endDate: NSDate = NSDate()
let dateComponents: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian).components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitNanosecond, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))
println("runtime is nanosecs : \(dateComponents.nanosecond)")
```

Comment: I just ran this with no code placed in the "// your long procedure", and it gave a result of 240900993, which is 0.24 seconds.

Comment: instantiating an `NSCalendar` is expensive procedure, but you can do it _before_ you start to run your procedure, so it won't be added to your long procedure's runtime... bear in mind calling creating an `NSDate` instance and calling `–components(_:, fromDate:)` method still takes time, so probably you will never get `0.0` nanoseconds.

Comment: From the looks of the NSCalendar constructor, it appears that it may not be possible to create it ahead of time (startDate is a required input).  It's kind of surprising that it seems to be such a hog.

Comment: you may do this (my updated answer), the measured time without any additional procedure is about `6.9` microseconds on my device.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  The basic procedure is now similar to JeremyP's answer, but the reporting is different.

Comment: If you multiply `timeInterval` in my answer by `1000000000` you'll get the answer in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
public class Stopwatch {
    public init() { }
    private var start_: NSTimeInterval = 0.0;
    private var end_: NSTimeInterval = 0.0;

    public func start() {
        start_ = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970;
    }

    public func stop() {
        end_ = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970;
    }

    public func durationSeconds() -> NSTimeInterval {
        return end_ - start_;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's more or less accurate than previously posted. But the seconds have a lot of decimals and seem to catch small code changes in algorithms like QuickSort using swap() vs. implementing swap urself etc.

Remember to crank up your build optimizations when testing performance:

[image: Swift compiler optimizations]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my try for the simplest answer:

```
let startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970  // 1512538946.5705 seconds

// time passes (about 10 seconds)

let endTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970    // 1512538956.57195 seconds
let elapsedTime = endTime - startTime         // 10.0014500617981 seconds
```

**Notes**

- `startTime` and `endTime` are of the type [`TimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval), which is just a `typealias` for `Double`, so it is easy to convert it to an `Int` or whatever. Time is measured in seconds with sub-millisecond precision.
- See also [`DateInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateinterval), which includes an actual start and end time.
- Using the time since 1970 is similar to [Java timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35884975/3681880).

Comment: easiest way, would like it in two strings, second is _let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime_

Answer (score 2):

[The recommend way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure) to check elapsed time/performance is using the `measure` function that is available in `XCTest`s.

It isn't reliable to write your own measure blocks, since the performance (and therefore execution/elapsed time) of a block of code is influenced by e.g. CPU caches.

The second time a function is invoked, would *likely* be quicker than the first time it is invoked, [although it can vary a few %](https://rbspy.github.io/benchmarking-your-code/). Therefore 'benchmarking' by using your own closures (given all over the place here) by executing it once, can give different results than your code being executed in production by real users.

The `measure` function invokes your block of code **several times**, mimicking the performance/elapsed time of your code like it is used in production ([at least gives more accurate results](https://mattwarren.org/2014/09/19/the-art-of-benchmarking/)).

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5+

I have borrowed the idea from Klaas to create a lightweight struct to measure running and interval time:

Code Usage:

```
var timer = RunningTimer.init()
// Code to be timed
print("Running: \(timer) ") // Gives time interval
// Second code to be timed
print("Running: \(timer) ") // Gives final time
```

The stop function does not have to be called, as the print function will give the time lapsed. It may be called repeatedly to get the time lapsed.
But to stop the timer at certain point in the code use `timer.stop()` it may also be used to return the time in seconds: `let seconds = timer.stop()`
After the timer is stopped the interval timer will not, so the `print("Running: \(timer) ")` will give the correct time even after a few lines of code.

Following is the code for RunningTimer. It is tested for Swift 2.1:

```
import CoreFoundation
// Usage:    var timer = RunningTimer.init()
// Start:    timer.start() to restart the timer
// Stop:     timer.stop() returns the time and stops the timer
// Duration: timer.duration returns the time
// May also be used with print(" \(timer) ")

struct RunningTimer: CustomStringConvertible {
    var begin:CFAbsoluteTime
    var end:CFAbsoluteTime
    
    init() {
        begin = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        end = 0
    }

    mutating func start() {
        begin = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        end = 0
    }

    mutating func stop() -> Double {
        if (end == 0) { end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() }
        return Double(end - begin)
    }

    var duration:CFAbsoluteTime {
        get {
            if (end == 0) { return CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - begin } 
            else { return end - begin }
        }
    }

    var description:String {
         let time = duration
         if (time > 100) {return " \(time/60) min"}
         else if (time < 1e-6) {return " \(time*1e9) ns"}
         else if (time < 1e-3) {return " \(time*1e6) µs"}
         else if (time < 1) {return " \(time*1000) ms"}
         else {return " \(time) s"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it up in a completion block for easy use.

```
public class func secElapsed(completion: () -> Void) {
    let startDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    completion()
    let endDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    let timeInterval: Double = endDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)
    println("seconds: \(timeInterval)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static Swift3 class for basic function timing. It will keep track of each timer by name. Call it like this at the point you want to start measuring:

```
Stopwatch.start(name: "PhotoCapture")
```

Call this to capture and print the time elapsed:

```
Stopwatch.timeElapsed(name: "PhotoCapture")
```

This is the output:  *** PhotoCapture elapsed ms: 1402.415125
There is a "useNanos" parameter if you want to use nanos.
Please feel free to change as needed.

```
   class Stopwatch: NSObject {

  private static var watches = [String:TimeInterval]()

  private static func intervalFromMachTime(time: TimeInterval, useNanos: Bool) -> TimeInterval {
     var info = mach_timebase_info()
     guard mach_timebase_info(&info) == KERN_SUCCESS else { return -1 }
     let currentTime = mach_absolute_time()
     let nanos = currentTime * UInt64(info.numer) / UInt64(info.denom)
     if useNanos {
        return (TimeInterval(nanos) - time)
     }
     else {
        return (TimeInterval(nanos) - time) / TimeInterval(NSEC_PER_MSEC)
     }
  }

  static func start(name: String) {
     var info = mach_timebase_info()
     guard mach_timebase_info(&info) == KERN_SUCCESS else { return }
     let currentTime = mach_absolute_time()
     let nanos = currentTime * UInt64(info.numer) / UInt64(info.denom)
     watches[name] = TimeInterval(nanos)
  }

  static func timeElapsed(name: String) {
     return timeElapsed(name: name, useNanos: false)
  }

  static func timeElapsed(name: String, useNanos: Bool) {
     if let start = watches[name] {
        let unit = useNanos ? "nanos" : "ms"
        print("*** \(name) elapsed \(unit): \(intervalFromMachTime(time: start, useNanos: useNanos))")
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: Your whole work with `mach_timebase_info` is already implemented better than you did in the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/CoreFoundation/NumberDate.subproj/CFDate.c) of [`ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1414553-systemuptime). So simply do `watches[name] = ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime`. And `* TimeInterval(NSEC_PER_MSEC)` if you want nanos.

Answer (score 1):

From Swift 5.7 (macOS 13.0, iOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0, tvOS 16.0), you can use `ContinuousClock` and the `measure` block, which returns a [`Duration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration?changes=_8) object. It has components that contain the measured time in seconds or [attoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attosecond), which is 1×10<sup>−18</sup> of a second.

```
let clock = ContinuousClock()

let duration = clock.measure {
    // put here what you want to measure
}

print("Duration: \(duration.components.seconds) seconds")
print("Duration: \(duration.components.attoseconds) attoseconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet I came up with and it seems to work for me on my Macbook with Swift 4.

Never tested on other systems, but I thought it's worth sharing anyway.

```
typealias MonotonicTS = UInt64
let monotonic_now: () -> MonotonicTS = mach_absolute_time

let time_numer: UInt64
let time_denom: UInt64
do {
    var time_info = mach_timebase_info(numer: 0, denom: 0)
    mach_timebase_info(&time_info)
    time_numer = UInt64(time_info.numer)
    time_denom = UInt64(time_info.denom)
}

// returns time interval in seconds
func monotonic_diff(from: MonotonicTS, to: MonotonicTS) -> TimeInterval {
    let diff = (to - from)
    let nanos = Double(diff * time_numer / time_denom)
    return nanos / 1_000_000_000
}

func seconds_elapsed(since: MonotonicTS) -> TimeInterval {
    return monotonic_diff(from: since, to:monotonic_now())
}
```

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
let t1 = monotonic_now()
// .. some code to run ..
let elapsed = seconds_elapsed(since: t1)
print("Time elapsed: \(elapsed*1000)ms")
```

Another way is to do it more explicitly:

```
let t1 = monotonic_now()
// .. some code to run ..
let t2 = monotonic_now()
let elapsed = monotonic_diff(from: t1, to: t2)
print("Time elapsed: \(elapsed*1000)ms")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I wrote it.

```
 func measure<T>(task: () -> T) -> Double {
        let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        task()
        let endTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        let result = endTime - startTime
        return result
    }
```

To measure a algorithm **use** it like that.

```
let time = measure {
    var array = [2,4,5,2,5,7,3,123,213,12]
    array.sorted()
}

print("Block is running \(time) seconds.")
```

Comment: How accurate is that time? Because I used timer before to update every 0.1 seconds. I compared this answer and one with timer and result from this answer is 0.1 seconds is more then with timer..

Answer (score 0):

### Based on [Franklin Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450692/4488252) answer and [Cœur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1033581/c%C5%93ur) comments

### Details

- Xcode 10.1 (10B61)
- Swift 4.2

### Solution 1

[measure(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure)

### Solution 2

```
import Foundation

class Measurer<T: Numeric> {

    private let startClosure: ()->(T)
    private let endClosure: (_ beginningTime: T)->(T)

    init (startClosure: @escaping ()->(T), endClosure: @escaping (_ beginningTime: T)->(T)) {
        self.startClosure = startClosure
        self.endClosure = endClosure
    }

    init (getCurrentTimeClosure: @escaping ()->(T)) {
        startClosure = getCurrentTimeClosure
        endClosure = { beginningTime in
            return getCurrentTimeClosure() - beginningTime
        }
    }

    func measure(closure: ()->()) -> T {
        let value = startClosure()
        closure()
        return endClosure(value)
    }
}
```

### Usage of solution 2

```
// Sample with ProcessInfo class

m = Measurer { ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime }
time = m.measure {
    _ = (1...1000).map{_ in Int(arc4random()%100)}
}
print("ProcessInfo: \(time)")

// Sample with Posix clock API

m = Measurer(startClosure: {Double(clock())}) { (Double(clock()) - $0 ) / Double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) }
time = m.measure {
    _ = (1...1000).map{_ in Int(arc4random()%100)}
}
print("POSIX: \(time)")
```

Comment: Not sure why we would need to use variable implementations. Using `Date` to measure anything is extremely discouraged (but `systemUptime` or `clock()` are OK). As for tests, we have [`measure(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measure) already.

Comment: Another note: why making the closure optional?

Comment: @Cœur you right! Thanks for your comments. I will update post later.