# How to remove duplicate elements inside an array - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I want to remove duplicate elements from an array. there are many answers in stack overflow but for swift 3.

my array:

```
var images = [InputSource]()
... // append to array
```

how to remove duplicate elements from this array?

Is there any native api from swift 3 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/does-there-exist-within-swifts-api-an-easy-way-to-remove-duplicate-elements-fro has answers for all Swift versions.

Comment: what have you tried from stackOverflow ? What issues are you facing ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709066/remove-duplicate-objects-in-an-array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that `InputSource` implements `Hashable`, otherwise Swift can't know which elements are equal and which are not.

You just do this:

```
let withoutDuplicates = Array(Set(images))
```

Explanation:

`images` is turned into a set first. This removes all the duplicates because sets can only contain distinct elements. Then we convert the set back to an array.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37141901/5133585), this is probably optimized by the compiler.

The disadvantage of this is that it might not preserve the order of the original array.

Comment: How to implements my array as Hashable?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian There are a lot of implementations of `hashcode`. The idea is that each distinct instance has a different hashcode. If two instances have the same hashcode, they are considered "equal". Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34705912/5133585

Comment: @S.M_Emamian:  Example in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34709118/1187415 to the "duplicate".

Comment: This will not preserve element order of the original array!

Comment: @ErikAigner True. Added a note to say that.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Set

// Initialize the Array
`var sample = [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,1,4,3,6,5]`

// Remove duplicates:
`sample = Array(Set(sample))`

`print(sample)`

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important, you should use a `Set` instead. Sets only contain unique elements. You can also create a `Set` from the array, that should eliminate duplicates.