# Inaccurate DispatchTime.now() in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm using DispatchTime.now() to measure elapsed time between events. Sometimes it works correctly, but occasionally it generates values that are far below what I would expect.

My current usage:

```
var t = DispatchTime.now()
var pt = DispatchTime.now()

// called when an event happens
t = DispatchTime.now()
var elapsed = Double(t.uptimeNanoseconds - pt.uptimeNanoseconds)
elapsed *= 32768/1000000000
pt = t
```

Such that t and pt are current and previous times, elapsed takes the difference in nanoseconds, converts to double, and scales such that 1 second = 32768.  When this technique fails the data recorded is about 100 times smaller than what is expected. The scaling is not the issue, I've checked the rawValue of t and pt. My assumption would be that the clock that runs DispatchTime is running at a slower speed, maybe because of debugging, but in general I would think iOS would compensate for something like this.

Comment: DispatchTime is meant for ... dispatch. It's subject to all kinds of deviations from wall ("regular") time, such as timer coalescing done by the OS.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Could you specify what you mean by dispatch? I saw an example of someone using DispatchTime and it seemed pretty clean but I suppose it isn't the best choice. Do you have a recommendation for measuring true time elapsed?

Comment: Grand Central Dispatch is the multi-threading framework for Swift. Using `DispatchTime` for anything other than specifying the time for `Dispatch` jobs is completely inappropriate, and will lead to wonky results like this. My solution here would depend on what exactly I'm looking to do, the kind of precision I want, the amount of performance I'm willing to pay for it, etc.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that framework so I don't misuse it again. I just need to measure elapsed time with a 32 kHz clock speed and accuracy of +- 10ms, should be easily achievable without any performance issues

Comment: Seems like `NSDate` will suffice for your need

Comment: Convenient, I was just wrapping up some code to test if NSDate would work. I'

Comment: Personally, when I'm looking for a low-overhead way of calculating elapsed time, I use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` or `CACurrentMediaTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexanderMomchliov suggested NSDate is a better approach than DispatchTime.

Implemented as:

```
var t: TimeInterval = 0
var pt: TimeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

// called when an event happens
t = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
var elapsed: Double = t - pt
elapsed *= 32768
pt = t
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing integer division which will result in inaccurate elapsed time:

```
elapsed *= 32768/1000000000
```

You should either wrap these as `Double` or end them with a decimal (i.e. `32768.0/1000000000.0`):

```
elapsed *= Double(32768)/Double(1000000000)
```

Additionally, `NSEC_PER_SEC` is defined as a global variable as part of the [Dispatch framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/nsec_per_sec):

```
elapsed *= Double(32768)/Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
```

`NSDate` or `Date` may be adjusted by the system and should not be used for reliably measuring elapsed time. [`DispatchTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime) or [`CACurrentMediaTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime) would be good solutions and are both based on mach absolute time. However, if the app is put in the background during measurement, then using `Date` would be a good fallback.

[Also recommend checking out this question for further discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755558/measure-elapsed-time-in-swift)