# SpriteKit & Swift, how to calculate the time spend in update, didEvaluateActions, didSimulatePhysics, didApplyConstraints and didFinishUpdate?

Tags: swift, performance, time, sprite-kit

Im trying to find out how much time SpriteKit spends in update, didEvaluateActions, didSimulatePhysics, didApplyConstraints and didFinishUpdate. This would allow me to find whether its my physics, actions, constraints or graphics that are slowing my game down sometimes. Im facing a fps drop of a few frames every now and then and this would be a good way to go i think. But how can i do that? I created a timeInterval() variable but how would i start and stop it?

```
    override func didEvaluateActions() {
    let currentTime = TimeInterval() // How to start? 

    print("didEvaluateActions: \(currentTime)")
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure elapsed time in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755558/measure-elapsed-time-in-swift)

Comment: I suggest you use the Time Profiler in Instruments to identify the problematic code.

Comment: @rakwaht sorry, must have missed that one. thanks, i will look into that.

Comment: @0x141E will look into that too, thank you.