# How to convert DispatchTimeInterval to NSTimeInterval (or Double)?

Tags: swift, nstimeinterval

I need to subtract a [`DispatchTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtimeinterval) from an [`NSTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimeinterval) (or `Double`).

Is there a standard way to convert a `DispatchTimeInterval` to an `NSTimeInterval`?

Comment: DispatchTimeInterval is used with DispatchTime, not with (NS)Date or (NS)TimeInterval. Can you tell more about why you need this? – In any case, DispatchTimeInterval is an enum, and converting it to a Double would be a matter of a simple switch/case.

Comment: @MartinR There's a timer which is set with a `DispatchTimeInterval` and I measure elapsed real time in `NSTimeInterval`. I need to subtract both to get a delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very neat and simple solution is this one **(no need for switch statements)**:

```swift
extension DispatchTimeInterval {
  var nanoseconds: UInt64 {
    let now = DispatchTime.now()
    let later = now.advanced(by: self)
    return later.uptimeNanoseconds - now.uptimeNanoseconds
  }

  var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
    return Double(nanoseconds) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

`DispatchTimeInterval` is a enum:

```
public enum DispatchTimeInterval : Equatable {
    case seconds(Int)
    case milliseconds(Int)
    case microseconds(Int)
    case nanoseconds(Int)
    case never
}
```

You can initialize `DispatchTimeInterval` using:

```
    let tenSeconds: DispatchTimeInterval = .seconds(10)
    let tenNanoseconds: DispatchTimeInterval = .nanoseconds(10)
```

To get values from enum you need to match value with a case values in enum

```
    if case .seconds(let value) = tenSeconds {
        print("DispatchTimeInterval is seconds \(value)")
    } else if case .nanoseconds(let value) = tenNanoseconds {
        print("DispatchTimeInterval is seconds \(value)")
    }
```

Converting function might be look following:

```
func toDouble(_ interval: DispatchTimeInterval) -> Double? {
        var result: Double? = 0

        switch interval {
        case .seconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)
        case .milliseconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)*0.001
        case .microseconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)*0.000001
        case .nanoseconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)*0.000000001

        case .never:
            result = nil
        }

        return result
    }
```

[More about Enumeration see in Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145)

UPDATE:

Create extension to `DispatchTimeInterval`

```
extension DispatchTimeInterval {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        var result: Double? = 0

        switch self {
        case .seconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)
        case .milliseconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)*0.001
        case .microseconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)*0.000001
        case .nanoseconds(let value):
            result = Double(value)*0.000000001

        case .never:
            result = nil
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A swifty solution would be to create a [`TimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval) extension and add a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) with a [`DispatchTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtimeinterval) parameter in it. The following Swift 5 code shows how to implement it:

```
import Foundation

extension TimeInterval {

    init?(dispatchTimeInterval: DispatchTimeInterval) {
        switch dispatchTimeInterval {
        case .seconds(let value):
            self = Double(value)
        case .milliseconds(let value):
            self = Double(value) / 1_000
        case .microseconds(let value):
            self = Double(value) / 1_000_000
        case .nanoseconds(let value):
            self = Double(value) / 1_000_000_000
        case .never:
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let dispatchTimeInterval = DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(5)
let timeInterval = TimeInterval(dispatchTimeInterval: dispatchTimeInterval)
print(String(describing: timeInterval)) // Optional(5.0)
```

```
let dispatchTimeInterval = DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(30)
let timeInterval = TimeInterval(dispatchTimeInterval: dispatchTimeInterval)
print(String(describing: timeInterval)) // Optional(0.03)
```