# Proper way to measure time in swift

Tags: swift

I am fooling around with a few languages and I want to compare time it takes to perform some computation. I have troubles with proper time measurement in swift. I am trying solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755558/measure-elapsed-time-in-swift) but I get improper results-the exeution takes much longer when i run `swift code.swift` than after compilation and the results are telling me the opposite:

```
 $  swiftc sort.swift -o csort
 gonczor  ~  Projects  Learning  Swift  timers 
 $  ./csort 
 Swift:  27858 ns
 gonczor  ~  Projects  Learning  Swift  timers 
 $  swift sort.swift 
 Swift:  22467 ns
```

This is the code:

```
iimport Dispatch
import CoreFoundation

var data = [some random integers]


func sort(data: inout [Int]){
    for i in 0..<data.count{
        for j in i..<data.count{
            if data[i] > data[j]{
                let tmp = data[i]
                data[i] = data[j]
                data[j] = tmp
            }
        }
    }
}

// let start = DispatchTime.now()
// sort(data: &data)
// let stop = DispatchTime.now()
// let nanoTime = stop.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
// let nanoTimeDouble = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000_000
let startTime = clock()
sort(data: &data)
let endTime = clock()
print("Swift:\t \(endTime - startTime) ns")
```

Same happens when I change timer to `clock()` call or use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` and whether I compare 1000 or 5000 element array.

**EDIT:**

To be clearer. I know that pasting one run does not produce statistically meaningful results but the problem is that I see one approach takes significantly longer than the other and I am told something different.

**EDIT2:**
It seems I am still not expressing my problem clear enough. I have created a bash script to show the problem.

I am using `time` utility to check how much time it takes to execute command. Once again: I am only fooling around, I do not need statistically meaningful results. I am just wondering why the swift utilities tell me something different that I am experiencing.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "swift sort.swift"
time swift sort.swift

echo "./cswift"
time ./csort
```

Result:

```
$  ./test.sh 
swift sort.swift
Swift:   22651 ns

real    0m0.954s
user    0m0.845s
sys 0m0.098s
./cswift
Swift:   25388 ns

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.033s
sys 0m0.008s
```

AS you can see the results using `time` show that it takes more or less 10 times longer to execute one command than another. And from the swift code I get info that it is more or less the same.

Comment: "but I get improper results" What does that mean exactly? What's the question?

Comment: @matt sorry. I'm tired and forgot to paste the test results. I've pasted what I get after executing.

Comment: Call me stupid but I don't see the problem. You are doing just one run of each and the results are in the same ballpark. Not statistically meaningful.

Comment: But as matt said, the problem isn't the choice of timer. It's the testing methodology.

Comment: @matt I can paste a 100 runs if you want with an array of size billion elements or something, but the problem is that I see that one approach takes longer and the other shorter  and yet the system tells me something different.

Comment: What do you mean "one iteration in Swift looks faster than your one iteration in C " I am not using C language here. And I've updated my answer. Hope it will be clearer now.

Comment: @Rob OK, I finally understood what you meant in previous comment. Yes, my methodology was flawed in other way than in terms of statistics. I've mistaken the "entire" code execution with what I actually measured. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Actually it's compiled same way as `csort`. As I say, it's late here (I'm in CET tz). Again: thanks for help, sorry for stupid question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. In terms of the best way to measure speed you can use `Date` or `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`, but you'll see that [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543542-cfabsolutetimegetcurrent) for those will warn you that

   > Repeated calls to this function do not guarantee monotonically increasing results.

   This is effectively warning you that, in the unlikely event that there is an adjustment to the system's clock in the intervening period, the calculated elapsed time may not be entirely accurate.

   It is advised to use `mach_time` if you need a great deal of accuracy when measuring the elapsed time. This involves some annoying CPU-specific adjustments (See [Technical Q&A 1398](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html).), but `CACurrentMediaTime` offers a simple alternative because it uses `mach_time` (which does not suffer this problem), but converts it to seconds to make it really easy to use.
2. The aforementioned notwithstanding, it seems that there is a more fundamental issue at play here: It looks like you're trying to reconcile a difference between to very different ways of running Swift code, namely:

   ```
   swiftc hello.swift -o hello
   time ./hello
   ```

   and

   ```
   time swift hello.swift
   ```

   The former is compiling `hello.swift` into a stand alone executable. The latter is loading `swift` REPL, which then effectively interprets the Swift code.

   This has nothing to do with the "proper" way to measure time. The time to execute the pre-compiled version should always be faster than invoking `swift` and passing it a source file. Not only is there more more overhead in invoking the latter, but the execution of the pre-compiled version is likely to be faster once execution starts, as well.
3. If you're really benchmarking the performance of running these routines, you should not rely on a single sort of 5000 items. I'd suggest sorting millions of items and repeating this multiple times and averaging the statistics. A single iteration of the sort is unsufficient to draw any meaningful conclusions.

Bottom line, you need to decide whether you want to benchmark just the execution of the code, but also the overhead of starting the REPL, too.