# Read Unix time from Swift

Tags: swift, ubuntu, raspbian, unix-timestamp

I'm playing with Swift for the first time and have some decent programs running under Ubuntu and on a Raspberry Pi but I cannot find a way to measure elapsed time. My first thought is to read the unix time but I cannot see it in any API and haven't figured out the FFI yet.

How should I measure elapsed time in Swift code on Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What's wrong with `Date`?

Comment: If you need accurate elapsed time, consider `mach_absolute_time` as outlined in [Technical Q&A 1398](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html).

Comment: Is NSDate an option? It is mentioned in this answer: [Measure elapsed time in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24755958/3112672)

Comment: My answer was converted into a comment so it can't be selected as an answer.  That is not right.

Comment: @absmiths - Effective with Swift 3, we don’t use `NSDate` anymore. We use `Date` nowadays.

Comment: What about the edit on the referenced answer to use DispatchTime.now()?  Is that available outside of iOS?

Comment: @absmiths `NSDate` won't compile on Linux.  You can check out some server side swift projects that are heavy in date/time management. This is one of them https://github.com/BrettRToomey/Jobs

Answer (score 1):

C is interoperable with Swift. If you don't want to use `Foundation`'s `Date` as rmaddy suggested,* you should be able to call the C stdlib's `time()` function. Just `import GlibC` first.

---

*The Unix time from a `Date` is just `Date.timeIntervalSince1970`.