# How to convert special character in normal string format

Tags: objective-c, iphone, string, ios7

Convert special characters like ë,à,é,ä all to e,a,e,a? Objective C

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18320825/3899770

```
NSMutableString *str = [@"Être ou ne pas être. C'était là-bas." mutableCopy];
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)string, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, NO);
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat answers (unless you want to add more relevant information). If you think that the question has been asked and answered before then you can flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, thanks for letting me know, was just trying to help the guy out