# swift remove diacritic from Arabic

Tags: swift, string, arabic, diacritics, arabic-support

I am trying to remove the Arabic text diacritic. For example I need to convert this `َب` to this `ب` , here is my code :

```
if (text != "") {
    for char in text! {
        print(char)
        print(char.unicodeScalars.first?.value)
        if allowed.contains("\(char)"){
            newText.append(char)
        }
    }
    self.textView.text = text!
} else {
//            TODO :
//            show an alert
    print("uhhh no way")
}
```

I have tried these solutions but with no luck :

[How to remove diacritics from a String in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521951/how-to-remove-diacritics-from-a-string-in-swift)

[NSString : easy way to remove UTF-8 accents from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932405/nsstring-easy-way-to-remove-utf-8-accents-from-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Regex, try this code

```
 let myString = "الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[\\u064b-\\u064f\\u0650-\\u0652]", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, myString.unicodeScalars.count)
        let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: "")
        print(modString)
```

> Output : الحمد لله رب العالمين

Answer (score 5):

Use this extension:

```
extension String {
    /// strip combining marks (accents or diacritics)
    var stripDiacritics: String {
        let mStringRef = NSMutableString(string: self) as CFMutableString
        CFStringTransform(mStringRef, nil, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, false)
        return mStringRef as String
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CFStringTransform`  with `kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks`

to remove `(accents or diacritics)`

```
        let original = "ََب"
        let mutableString = NSMutableString(string: original) as CFMutableString
        CFStringTransform(mutableString, nil, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, Bool(truncating: 0))
        let normalized = (mutableString as NSMutableString).copy() as! NSString

        print(normalized)
```

**CFStringTransform**

> A constant containing the transformation of a string by removing
>   combining marks.

**kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks**

> The identifier of a transform to strip combining marks (accents or diacritics).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#this code for arabic preporocessing
import pyarabic.araby as araby
import pyarabic.number as number

text = u'الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ'

#Strip Harakat from arabic word except Shadda.
from pyarabic.araby import strip_harakat
print(strip_harakat(text))
# الحمد للّه ربّ العالمين

#حذف الحركات بما فيها الشدة
#Strip vowels from a text, include Shadda.
from pyarabic.araby import strip_tashkeel
print(strip_tashkeel(text))
#الحمد لله رب العالمين
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Hashem-Aboonajmi answer

```
extension String {
    /// strip combining marks (accents or diacritics)
    func stripDiacritics(active: Bool) -> String {
        if !active {return self}
        let mStringRef = NSMutableString(string: self) as CFMutableString
        CFStringTransform(mStringRef, nil, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, false)
        return mStringRef as String
    }
}
```

in case you want to activate or deactivate

Comment: Just beware this method removes the ء also, so أ becomes ا and ئ become ى
There for I will see the other methods